# Is net entropy change 0 when we slowly increase concentration of a gas in a closed container at thermal contact with the environment?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

I suspect that the answer for the following question is no, but I hope I am wrong.

Consider the following process.

[image]

An ideal monoatomic gas is in a closed container, which is in thermal contact with the environment at constant temperature T. A tiny tube is connected to the container and pushes additional atoms of the same gas into the container at a very low rate. Let’s think these additional atoms arrive to the container with almost zero kinetic energy.
When a such atom shows up in the gas, it takes some energy (as heat δQ) from other atoms of the gas to have the same average kinetic energy, which corresponds to temperature T. In turn, the gas takes the same amount of energy δQ from the environment to compensate the loss due to the additional atom.

As understand, this process, if it occurs very slow, can be considered as isothermal (and isochoric), but with varying number N of atoms and pressure.

**The question:** If it is an isothermal process, can the entropy change for the environment and for the gas cancel each other, like in a “common” isothermal process with constant N?

$$\Delta S_{\rm sys}=-\Delta S_{\rm env}$$

I doubt that this is the case because it doesn’t look like a reversible process, but I would appreciate any comments or answers on this.

Just interesting... If the answer is no, the entropy change of the gas cannot be calculated as
$\Delta S_{\rm sys}=\frac{Q}{T}$. Then how can it be calculated in this process?

PS. Some thoughts.

In an isothermal expansion with constant N, the entropy of a gas is increasing due to occupation additional volume, the temperature and internal energy are same.

In the process I described above, the entropy of a gas is increasing due to additional number of particles and increase in internal energy, the temperature is the same again.

Comment: How can the process be isobaric if the pressure varies?

Comment: Where I am talking about an isobaric process?

Comment: Maybe I should have made an assumption that atoms flow in one direction through the tube, as shown in the picture, if it is what that concerns you.

Comment: Sorry.  I misread what you wrote.  So you initially have N1 molecules of gas at T1 and P1 within the fixed container volume, and you add N molecules of gas initially at T2<T1 and P2>P1 to the container so that, in the final state, you have N1+N2 molecules of the gas at T1 and whatever pressure (necessary to satisfy the idea gas law) within the fixed volume container?  And you want to determine the change in entropy of these masses of gas from the initial state to the final state?

Comment: That’s correct. I just would like to know whether such a process can be reversible (the net entropy change of the system and environment is 0), like for a ”usual” isothermal process (with N=const and V≠const). 

I guess this process can be reversible only if the entropy change of the gas can be calculated as $\Delta S_{sys}=\frac{Q_{sys}}{T}$, then combined with $\Delta S_{env}=\frac{Q_{env}}{T}$ it gives 0 for the total entropy change.

Comment: This is an open system, and entropy is entering the system via the gas flowing into the system.  So the change in entropy of the system is not just determined by the heat flow into the system, even if the process were reversible.  Anyway, if P2 is not the same as P1, you would need to have a throttling valve to allow the new gas to enter the system, and this would introduce some irreversibility.  In addition, if T2 is significantly different from T1, the temperature within the system would change during the injection, and there would be irreversibility from the heat transfer as well.

Comment: Okay. As I expected the answer is negative. Thank you.

Comment: I've found Knuiman et al.'s "*[On the Relation between the Fundamental Equation of Thermodynamics and the Energy Balance Equation in the Context of Closed and Open Systems](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed200405k)*" (2012) useful in avoiding pitfalls when considering heat and mass transfer in open systems.

Comment: Chemomechanics, thanks, I'll read this one.

Comment: @Chet Miller, one more question about this process. If we can provide $P_2 = P_1$ and make flow rate of the gas at temperature at $T_2 << T_1$ be infinitesimally low (only one particle arrives each time so that the temperature within the whole gas doesn’t change), can this process be considered as a reversible one?